# Is there a way or event to retrieve command line arguments on runtime

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments, media-player, windows-explorer, .net-4.6.1

so i'm trying to make a media player so far i'm in the final stage to publish my media player for poeple to download it i'm just having an issue where i need to capture command line argument on runtime , so far i've checked the run only one instance of the app and i can recieve command line argument when using Open With from windows explorer it works but what i need to do is to be able to recive command line arguments on runtime , assume you're using my app , you're listening to music and you found a music you love on a folder on your pc , you're so lazy to switch to the app and use the open file button you just want to double click the song and start listening , now if the app is closed when you double click the song it will play with no problem but if the app is running it won't play windows will just switch to the app.
So the question is : is there an event or a way to catch if command line argument is passed to the app on runtime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have indicated that you made the application a single instance application, it is very likely that you are using VB's Application framework.  This framework exposes the [StartupNextInstance Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance?view=netframework-4.8).  From the documentation for that event.

> You must use the CommandLine property of the e parameter to access the arguments for subsequent attempts to start a single-instance application.

To add a handler for that event, you can use the designer to create the handler via Project Menu->PropjectName Properties->Application Tab-View Application Events Button or just copy the following to a code file in your project.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
  Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
      ' use e.CommandLine
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Thank you @TnTinMn Works Like a charm i didn't know how to even call this event in google search , anyways , Thanks again