# Command line Argument at Runtime using single instance application

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments

I'm developing a small tools to receive command line argument. Argument is send during runtime.
I found from this article :

- [Is there a way or event to retrieve command line arguments on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469577/is-there-a-way-or-event-to-retrieve-command-line-arguments-on-runtime)
- [Pass Command Line to first instance of a Single Instance App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831765/pass-command-line-to-first-instance-of-a-single-instance-app)

and try to implemented using **startupnextinstance** events

my code is like this on ApplicationEvents

```
 Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
            Dim f = Application.MainForm
            If f.GetType Is GetType(Form1) Then
               CType(f, Form1).NewArgumentsReceived(e.CommandLine.ToArray)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

and in form1, I'm using this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim strFile As String = "d:\temp.txt"
    Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile)
    Public Sub NewArgumentsReceived(args As String())
        If args.Length > 0 Then
            Using sw As New StreamWriter(strFile)
                sw.WriteLine(args(0), Environment.NewLine)
                sw.Flush()
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm trying to send output to file (just for debugging).
When I'm try to run this application, I can't receive the argument that send to this tools (temp file is empty) also my tools in not run in single instance again

- https://prnt.sc/I_ov7SEDtcsp
- https://prnt.sc/7qr7yqggyrPX

My purpose is read command line argument that send at runtime and can read at every where form.

Any wrong with my code? Why single instance application is not working in here?

Comment: You don't need the file. Just use the debugger. Set breakpoints at the appropriate places and see whether they get hit. If they do, step through the code as required.

Comment: @John because this tools get run from other application not only debug from vb.net. so can't see tue result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing, it seems like there might be a bug in the single-instance application functionality when running in the debugger that causes the third and subsequent instances to throw an exception but it seems to work properly when running the application directly. Code-wise, I added this to `Form1`:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething(args As IEnumerable(Of String))
    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, args))
End Sub
```

and this to ApplicationEvents.vb:

```vb
Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
    TryCast(MainForm, Form1)?.DoSomething(e.CommandLine)
End Sub
```

In the project properties, I edited the Debug Launch Profiles and set the Command line arguments to "First Second Third" (without quotes). I then right-clicked on the project and selected Debug -> Start Without Debugging multiples times and all but the first instance displayed the expected message box. I was also able to start the app from a command prompt with commandline arguments and it worked as expected then too.

It's also worth noting that that event is not raised on the UI thread, so you may find that the message box in my example behaves a little strangely. In a real app, you should marshal a call to the UI thread to do something in `Form1` in most cases, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
    Dim f1 = DirectCast(MainForm, Form1)

    f1.Invoke(Sub() f1.DoSomething(e.CommandLine))
End Sub
```

That will make the message box in my example behave modally with respect to the form, which it doesn't if it's displayed on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks, already modified your solution to access argument not from main form. 

But the problem single-instance-application still showing if we shortcut F5, but if using "right-clicked on the project and selected Debug -> Start Without Debugging", it's work perfectly.

Comment: @cloudrider, starting multiple instances in the debugger works for a .NET Framework project but not for a .NET Core project, which includes .NET 5 and later. All that stuff had to be reimplemented from scratch for .NET Core and there are still a few things not working properly or missing. This is clearly a bug and should be reported to Microsoft as such.